Why is my gradient background workflow so redundant?
I often use an alpha background in my render animations, so that in the VSE I can add a gradient background. That way I can customize the background later and choose an appropriate color. The way I am doing it now feels so wrong, and I am sure there is a better way.
Here is how I do it now:

Create a blend file with only a camera, and make the world material a gradient.
Rotate the camera to find a gradient orientation that looks good.
Render image and save.
Use in VSE as background for anything with alpha channel.

Some hassles that arise are:

Do I really have to go back and change the color ramp for whichever gradient background I want to use?
I cannot change rotation of the gradient if it is unacceptable.






What is your motivation to not render the world at the same time, for example with the Environment pass ? I would recommend not using the VSE (e.g. hard limit of 8bit colors), especially if you can achieve the same easily in compositing.

Why not using the compositor?

you could also use a simple plane in the background ;) but to "answer" your question: this link explains exactly what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7bQdH-L_pk

@Lutzi I think that would render the world every frame of the video, which would be a waste, right?

@JBRiley Rendering a gradient should be lightning quick. Is it really a waste worth using VSE and a workflow you don't like ?

@Lutzi thanks. The answer below was perfect. Using a mask as a reveal for a gradient is just what I needed. thanks for your help lutzi

So essentially you just have to create a mask (one time/the gradient), use the mask modifier + 2 colors like this:


the most upper image/movie is your foreground
the gradient (just hide it)
the first color (red) with mask modifier - strip blend: alpha over:



the second color (blue)  - strip blend: replace

result:

good thing is, you can still rotate/scale your mask to your liking:

video tutorial:  https://youtu.be/y7bQdH-L_pk?si=apxyA6QvQNYOTTet
